# Filtering Pivot Tables with Multi Level Index - pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, filtering

I have a dataset with 4 columns - 2 are unique identifiers, one is a year label, and one is a sales label.

I need to filter for the year with most sales, for each item (i.e. subject to both identifiers).

I can't figure out how to match up the maximum sales to the year in which it occurs.

I have tried to use df.pivot(index = ['ID1','ID2'], values = 'sales', aggfunc = 'max') to create a pivot table that gives me the maximum that occurs in a single year. But I don't see how to relate this back to the year in which it occurs.

I've also tried df.pivot(index = ['ID1','ID2','year'], values = 'sales', aggfunc = 'max'), but this simply repeats the dataset since it can't compare the max sales in a given year across years - it just tells you the maximum for each year which is basically identical to the data set.

Comment: Please include code to generate a mock dataset along with expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.